# FlowJs: Howto type predicate functions?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I'm trying to implement some kind of a generic redux reducer in my application that should handle error [flux standard actions](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action) with flow types.

Suppose I have the Flowtype definition for FSA:

```
type Action<P, M = void> = {
  type: string,
  payload: P,
  meta?: M,
  error?: boolean
}
```

Where `P` might be an instance of an error. Also, I have custom [predicate function](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions) to detect error actions:

```
function isErrorAction<P, M>(a: Action<P, M>): boolean %checks {
  return a.payload instanceof Error;
}
```

As documentation mentions the body of this function is the simple expression.

Finally, I have the simple generic action handler:

```
function handle(a: Action<string | Error>) {
  if (isErrorAction(a)) {
    console.log(a.payload.message);
  }
}
```

But Flowtype complains about:

```
console.log(a.payload.message);
                              ^ Cannot get `a.payload.message` because property `message` is missing in `String` [1].
```

When I inline the predicate function within the action handler everything works fine. So probably I'm missing something about predicate functions.

[[try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAxhgJZwB2APAAoA0YAsmALxgBucZAJgHxswAb1RgwOAIZZ4EngC4wDUWAC2eDBID8CpqgC+6KAFdKpCpTBkAzgFEATnbh2S5KnUZM+ACgkKX592Y+AEoFACM4OBg8CQsAUmIACzxiAGsrYWU7dSM7CwkAOklpOFlLSisNUzw4KDB7RzsAbn1DEzMqMETYnmiARh8-DppKuzJKAHMwAB96hycQzLEyOq9rBqd-Kh9g4KWxMGIqKyi8AvgJnyKpGR4CtSsrCQm8YJaxAwNUY1NXC27KL08AAmQZEYbUUbjKazDZ2RYiZarQrFW7lSqxYg1OpwvaIg5HCqnc5wS4om6lO4PJ4vN7KT5AA)]

Answer (score 2):

In your original example, I think that's a failing of Flow's predicate functions, it seems to work fine when the subject is the argument, but not when its a member of an argument.

However, it seems that you want some syntactic sugar, in which case, [Disjoint Unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) to the rescue!

NB: You must test either `payload` or `error` for existence (truthy) before use, or it will warn that it could be handling the other type, hence the else condition before accessing `a.payload`.

([Try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAziggg4BLA9gOwB4AFAGigFkoBeKAN12wBMA+GqAbwB8AoKKMAEMQAG1yCmALihk+UALYRgggPzSKpHlwC+PHqEhQAYoOwi4AJwiYcBEuSq0GzNrW5yIFi7gvSAol4+mvyKymqUmjp6BtA2eERklOzOrOzwSKgYWPH2lGxcxqbmVnF2iRQsegBmcPjZBFAAFoL4TCIQAIwAFILSpUQowBbY+ADmLACUnHLYVVA9AHSe3hZTHHL8CAQouO1LgRaLyz4LimiCoxATANxy2lAQIijQ6wCQW-g7e2Kji0Ki4iYEzuPF0PA+gygKEQyDQ7A4AmEYgk0gA5CBhKioNpbhDgA8DvCCStpPgIAB3KABFZdVEAIx8AGtUVMcTwutCMmhpOlYVlbAMhiNxjdXgB6MUyQRodmcvnSExmSzWeqC4ZjSbXcWSxUiaQAYRa+Fw+IQ0vxAAM5ZkLVBgLgoBbdcr+ra6RAzXBngJvJALKBHccLLbsCgFKGUMKoCMoLg6QArD34kTYYCeQQidlBhVFF2qwiDdUirXaqUyrrZ2AwzL9AtCjWi0u6g1Gk1QM2Qi1B232x28muqt0ewRe6BgX2eANdg4hsPyCNRmMW-toV16PFQBnARpE-7IqRQdGY8iVsmU6k+WkMizM1nXKDsreNPr5wvCzWvT9NorSLpCCyCGAjQAc8QIPKmjSeIGM6xhYjp7oCs7hmgwrrts+JkhBUFuNi97sph26eC+Ap1kWH6fhKhRmL+-6AcB0oQGBIwQAAHoIWBQCmaYASIUDGqauDyEIOB0u0UDkhBfbVqug6wY6zolIOQA))

```
type SuccessAction<P, M = void> = {|
  payload: P,
  meta?: M,
|}

type FailureAction<P, M = void> = {|
  error: Error,
  meta?: M,
|}

type Action<P, M = void> = SuccessAction<P, M> | FailureAction<P, M>

function handle1(a: Action<string>) {
  if (a.error) {
    console.error(a.error.message);
  } else {
    console.log(a.payload)
  }
}

const success = { payload: 'yay' };
const error = { error: new Error('bork') };
(success: SuccessAction<string>);   // Pass
(success: FailureAction<string>);   // Fail: Cannot cast `success` to `FailureAction` because property `error` is missing in object literal
(error: FailureAction<string>);     // Pass
(error: SuccessAction<string>);     // Fail: Cannot cast `error` to `SuccessAction` because property `error` is missing in `SuccessAction`

const both = { payload: 'yay', error: new Error('bork') }; 
(both: Action<string>);             // Fail: (paraphrased) either `error` or `payload` is missing

const neither = { }; 
(neither: Action<string>);          // Fail: (paraphrased) inexact literal not compatible with `SuccessAction` or `FailureAction`
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I'm tied to flux standard action, so an action must have only `payload` property, `error` property is optional and should be boolean. But I've modified your approach: [try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKArgMal4DOlAgqRgJZwB2APAAoA0YAsgHxgAvGADeAH1Rgw2fAC4wlDACcGzAOadJYHAEMs8HQBN5XLQFs8GHQH55PTVLxKlcJbbBQdMSnlRiAvgDc6DIEAKLOrnSMLKz8QqISUqHyiirqDtp6BsZgES5KmRZW7vZaTgXyysS+AcGYuATRTGxcRDwJAG5wDIbcYR3C3b0CwiTkVLT0LRzchPFieZFKzbEDfPVQxMzTLGAAFjrMhjB4q61z9nn8ABQ6u8zy57Pt-fwAlKJaDFBgdw8AOgqrk+Ii0UlILEocFOAPgan+MWYAN0+jgRgBFmoOjUeHewSk-lQ-iAA)

Comment: You don't necessarily need SM and EM if meta is the same type in both success and failure.  Strictly speaking, according to the flux docs, payload can be optional, but is an Error by convention.  If you make it `payload?`, you'll need an additional check before accessing `action.payload.message`, e.g. `if (action.error && action.payload)`

Comment: Agreed, but I've intentionally added payload as required to reduce this predicate expression. It is a tradeoff `P` can be declared as `void` in case of empty payload

Answer (score 1):

Looks like flowtype cannot refine properties from an object in predicate function: [github tread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4723#issuecomment-369997237)

Personally, I've ended up with following [modification](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKArgMal4DOlAgqRgJZwB2APAAoA0YAsgHxgAvGADeAH1Rgw2fAC4wlDACcGzAOadJYHAEMs8HQBN5XLQFs8GHQH55PTVLxKlcJbbBQdMSnlRiAvgDc6DIEAKLOrnSMLKz8QqISUqHyiirqDtp6BsZgES5KmRZW7vZaTgXyysS+AcGYuATRTGxcRDwJAG5wDIbcYR3C3b0CwiTkVLT0LRzchPFieZFKzbEDfPVQxMzTLGAAFjrMhjB4q61z9nn8ABQ6u8zy57Pt-fwAlKJaDFBgdw8AOgqrk+Ii0UlILEocFOAPgan+MWYAN0+jgRgBFmoOjUeHewSk-lQ-iAA) of [Dave Meehan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063521/flowjs-howto-type-predicate-functions/49072706#49072706)